# ionic native api not working with vue, how to achieve it?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

when i install
npm install cordova-plugin-native-ringtones in my ionic vue project got this following error

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@ionic-native/native-ringtones/ngx/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/afzal-8396/Desktop/other_frameworks/ionic/myApp/node_modules/@ionic-native/native-ringtones/ngx'

Answer (score 0):

you dont import the ngx..

from the documentation...

```
npm install cordova-plugin-native-ringtones
npm install @ionic-native/native-ringtones
ionic cap sync
```

in yout file

```
import { NativeRingtones } from '@ionic-native/native-ringtones

NativeRingtones.getRingtone().then((ringtones) => { console.log(ringtones); });
```

Comment: thanks that worked , but got the error 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ionic_native_native_ringtones_ngx__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.NativeRingtones.getRingtone is not a function
But console.log("NativeRingtones",NativeRingtones) printed the function. but console.log("NativeRingtones",NativeRingtones.getRingtone) is undefined . any idea?

Comment: post your code... you are still not doing something correctly

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zkmu3o4y/1/)
this is my component code , thanks in advance